# How to make a Progress bar and Progress Dialog that resembles iPhone's progress bar?

Tags: android, progress-bar

How can i make a Progress bar and Progress Dialog in Android that should resemble IPhone progress bar.

Comment: What does the iphone progress bar look like?

Comment: That's how it looks http://cazisoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/iphone-progress.jpg

Now i want to make it in Android.Any clue?

Comment: apple would probably have an issue with you using their logo on android.

Comment: Common! I don't want the logo...:). All i need is a progress bar resembling iPhone's progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Android documentation on [Building Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).  Basically you should be able to do this by overriding the onDraw method and adding your own functions to set/get the state of the progress bar.  Read through that article and you should have a good idea on how to get started making your own progress bar component.

Or just override the onDraw in your own [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) derived class